# Book (for elementary school children) about a girl whose mother was kidnapped and hidden in an underground cave + there's a color-blind truck driver

Tags: identification-request

This book is about a young-ish girl who lives in a fancy but depressing place and takes some sort of music lessons. Her mother was kidnapped and I believe she is being hidden in some sort of cave (or at least that was how I imagined it). I remember the main character wondering about how much longer her mother would survive if she didn't have access to water, and I have the idea that she decided to look for her where a river could run through and provide water.

There is also a notable scene with a color-blind truck driver (who is employed by a bad guy?) and deals with some sad feelings (maybe about his own mother?) and I believe the girl hides away in the back of the truck (I think it was a dump truck, so among the garbage) and convinces him to do the right thing. I read this book probably over a decade ago, but it wasn't that old at the time.

Do any books come to mind? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.